# Evaluate $(1+i)^{-i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponentiation

$(1+i)^{-i}$

I need to find all the possible values

$r=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$

$\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$

$[\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}]^{-i}$

How to continue from here?

Comment: How do you define the complex number $$z^w$$ when $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, already?

Comment: If you multiply through the -i you should have in your last step, you will get $2^{(-i/2)} e^{(π/4)}$

Comment: @Did I do not know

Comment: Then what does this question even mean to you?

Comment: @Did I want to find all the possible values, I think that I need to get to $re^{i\alpha+2\pi k}$ form

Answer (score 8):

\begin{align}\bigl(\sqrt2e^{\frac{\pi i}4}\bigr)^{-i}&=\exp\left(-i\left(\log\bigl(\sqrt2\bigr)+\frac{\pi i}4+2k\pi i\right)\right)\\&=\exp\left(-\frac{\log2}2i+\frac\pi4+2k\pi\right)\\&=e^{\frac\pi4+2k\pi}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\log2}2\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{\log2}2\right)\right),\end{align}with $k\in\mathbb Z$. If you just want to use the principal value of the logarithm, take $k=0$.

Comment: Or... $(-1)^{-\frac{i}{4}} 2^{-\frac{i}{2}}$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork No. Please see comments on main.